# How do I send an email automatically to myself when the user clicks on a button in my app?

Tags: android

Let's say I have an app that has numeros products for sale as well as the details. I would like when the user clicks on a button for an email to be sent automatically to myself with the product information how would I go about doing this? Essentially what I am trying to do here is allow the user to order a product from my app and send an email automatically to myself with the information about the product. I already tried researching this but I only found sources on how to send an email via From an app.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124

Answer (score 0):

> You need to have a server for that. If you are using GMailSender library or anything like that it is not reliable.. You need a hosting server and it can send your mail to any hosting mail sites. On the other hand GMailSender  will only send mail's to gmail accounts..